# Why MySQL GROUP_CONCAT returns NULL when there are some non-NULL values

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Here is some sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  first_name VARCHAR(255),
  last_name VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO test (first_name) VALUES ('first_1');
INSERT INTO test (last_name) VALUES ('last_1');

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(first_name, last_name) FROM test;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(first_name), GROUP_CONCAT(last_name) FROM test;
```

The first select returns null, while the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) states that it returns null if there are no non-NULL values.
[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Gu1aGGzw3TfX1uBQDg17C/0) is a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is expected.  Consider the first query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(first_name, last_name) FROM test;
```

Because each record has a `NULL` for either the first or last name, you are concatenating a `NULL` value and then aggregating on that `NULL`, also yielding `NULL`.  To understand this behavior better, run the query `SELECT CONCAT('Hello', NULL) FROM dual` and observe that the output is `NULL`.

However, in the second query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(first_name), GROUP_CONCAT(last_name) FROM test;
```

You are group concatenating on the individual *columns*.  In this case, the `NULL` values will be *ignored*, and you are left with the non `NULL` first and last name individual values.

Diagrammatically, we can draw the following:

```
first_name | last_name | CONCAT (first_name, last_name)
first_1    | NULL      | NULL
NULL       | last_1    | NULL
--------------------------------
first_1    | last_1    | NULL    <-- GROUP_CONCAT of columns
```

You can see that `GROUP_CONCAT` across records behaves like the other aggregate functions, ignoring `NULL` values.  But across *columns*, `GROUP_CONCAT` will do a concatenation first, resulting in `NULL` if even one value be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

use `having`

```
SELECT
    `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`, `b`.`id` AS  `b_id`, `b`.`name` AS  `b_name`,   GROUP_CONCAT(  `c`.`l_id` ) AS  `c_ls`
FROM  
    `a`
    INNER JOIN  `b` ON  `a`.`b_id` =  `b`.`id`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `c` ON  `a`.`id` = `c`.`a_id`
having `a`.`id` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`created` DESC
```